# Debugging a virtual machine - should I look at the internal or external network interface?

Tags: networking, network-interface, monitoring

I've setup a virtual machine, that performs really poorly. It's a VirtualBox controlled Vagrant. I'm trying to understand why it takes somewhere between 5 seconds and 30 seconds for this VM to load a simple page on a WordPress site.

I've installed [bpytop](https://github.com/aristocratos/bpytop) on the VM and are looking at the stats, when I refresh a page.

**VM-specs**

- Processors: 4
- Base memory: 8192MB
- OS: 20.04.2

**Grand overarching question:** Should I look at `eth0` or `eth1`, when debugging this?
I see activity on both interfaces and are struggling to figure out what comes from what - and what is interesting in this case.

---

#### Further details

Whenever I'm reloading a page, I assume the request travels like this:

**When refreshing a page**

```
(Macbook)        (VM)
My browser -->-- Eth1 -->-- Eth0 -->-- Nginx -->-- PHP-stuff -->-- DB-calls --
                                                                              ˅
                                                                              ˅
Reload done --<-- Eth1 --<-- Eth0 --<-- Nginx --<-- PHP-stuff ----------------˅
```

Is that right?
... If so, then I would imagine that I had to look for the weak part of that chain.

If I look at the network interfaces, upon refreshing a page, I was hoping to see where the long wait was. But I don't know which interface I should be looking at:

**Eth1 upon activity**

[image: eth1 activity]

**Eth0 upon activity**

[image: eth0 activity]

I can see when what happens, by running: `tcpdump -i any port not 22` via the SSH-tunnel, on my VM.

And this setup is running on both a staging-server and a production-server on Digital Ocean, where it responds really quickly (>5 seconds).

It annoys the heck out of me, that the online version of this setup is faster than my local!

---

### Solution attempts

**nload**

I tried finding another network monitoring tool, to make it easier to see both `eth0` and `eth1` at the same time. The best one I found was [nload](https://www.tecmint.com/nload-monitor-linux-network-traffic-bandwidth-usage/). But it didn't give me any new insights. But because the units scoot between `Bit/s`, `kBit/s` and `MBit/s`, so it's impossible to get a good quick overview 'at a glance'.

Here's how it looks at a random point in time:

[image: nload]

**Play around with the shared folders**

I read a lot about how shared folders can put quite the burden on these VMs. I played around with NFS (and the `nfsd`) on my host-machine. But based on the TCPdump, then it doesn't look like that it's the culprit regarding why the Nginx-server responds slowly.